# In R, how to use regex [:punct:] in gsub?

Tags: regex, r

Given

```
test<-"Low-Decarie, Etienne"
```

I wish to replace all punctuation with space

```
gsub(pattern="[:punct:]", x=test, replacement=" ")
```

but this produces

```
"Low-De arie, E ie  e"
```

where no punctuation is replaced and apparently random letters are removed (though they may be associated with punctation as t for tab and n for next line).

Comment: `pattern="[[:punct:]]"`...

Comment: The Examples section of `?gsub` gives examples of the answer @kohske provided.  And the removed letters aren't random; they're in the set of {p,u,n,c,t,:}.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Fellow MontReal user here.

Several options, sames results.

In R Base, just double the brackets

```
gsub(pattern="[[:punct:]]", test, replacement=" ")

[1] "Low Decarie  Etienne"
```

Package `stringr` has function `str_replace_all` that does that.

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(test, "[[:punct:]]", " ")
```

Or keep only letters

```
str_replace_all(test, "[^[:alnum:]]", " ")
```